# Sort json objects by priority then randomize everything els

Tags: jquery, json, object, random

Maybe someone can help. Can't figure out this by my self :(
I have list of json objects:

```
{"widget_foto": {"photos": [
    {
        "picThumb": "../../preview_stuff/img/widget-3-1.png",
        "picOrig": "../../preview_stuff/img/widget-3-1.png",
        "galeryUrl": "",
        "shareUrl": "",
        "priority": 0
    },
    {
        "picThumb": "../../preview_stuff/img/widget-3-2.png",
        "picOrig": "../../preview_stuff/img/widget-3-2.png",
        "galeryUrl": "",
        "shareUrl": "",
        "priority": 2
    },}}
```

I need to order objects by priority, what I have done already, but I can't figure out how to randomize objects that have priority 0 or if object priorities are equal.

Here's my code so far.

```
$(function(){
var url="../json/foto.json";
$.getJSON(url, function(json){
    var fotoWidget = json.widget_foto;
    var widget3 = ".col-widget-3" + " ";

    //Populate content
    var byPriority = fotoWidget.photos.slice(0);

    byPriority.sort(function(a,b){
        return b.priority - a.priority;
    });
    $.each(byPriority, function(index, value){
        $(widget3 + ".widget-3-" + (index + 1)).css({"background-image": "url(images/" + value.picOrig + ")"});
    });
});
```

Any help will be apriciated.

Comment: Add a 'sortorder' property, set it to `.priority + "." + random_number()` then sort on that.  Remove it after the sort if you don't need it later.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can randomly shuffle the array first, then sort by priority.

```
var data = [
    {id:"0", "p":0},
    {id:"1", "p":0},
    {id:"2", "p":5},
    {id:"3", "p":5},
    {id:"4", "p":2},
    {id:"5", "p":2},
    {id:"6", "p":4},
    {id:"7", "p":4},
    {id:"8", "p":1},
    {id:"9", "p":1}
]
function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}
shuffleArray(data)
data.sort( (a, b) => a.p - b.p )
JSON.stringify(data)
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, returns an array the same order like in json file. :(

Comment: I edited the answer to provide full code you can directly paste into your console.